# Image is does not show in ImageView dynamically from sdcard

Tags: android

In My Code The image is not open in ImageView from sdcard i already checked the permissions in 'manifest.xml'.
Same if i try to open it using static name then it will showed by ImageView but not dynamically.

**Main Activity**

```
private OnClickListener OnCapture =  new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String time = mCamUtils.clickPicture();
        nextActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,EffectActivity.class);
        nextActivity.putExtra("ImageName", time);
        startActivity(nextActivity);
        finish();
    }
};
```

**EffectActivity**

```
    public class EffectActivity extends Activity {

Intent getActivity = null;
ImageView image = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.effectactivity);

    getActivity = getIntent();
    String name = getActivity.getStringExtra("ImageName");

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/GalaxyPhoto/GX_" +name+ ".JPG";

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    File f = new File(path);
    byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    if(f.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            if(f.exists())
            {
                FileInputStream ff = new FileInputStream(f);
                ff.read(b);
                Bitmap g = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                image.setImageBitmap(g);
                ff.close();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ELSE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to open image which i saved in before this activity and i catch the name of image here but that does not show the image.

Comment: show code where saving image on sdcard and starting `EffectActivity` Activity

Comment: Its to long and behind it 6 class working and image saved in folder i checked it name is also print it TOAST but still image not open in ImageView

Comment: Are you getting in exception while loading an image?

Comment: @ John Hans: ok then show only code where starting activity instead of whole code from class

Comment: @JohnHans: try it as `Bitmap g = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);`

Comment: i already try please see my code sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/GalaxyPhoto/GX_" +name+ ".JPG";
```

In this line try changing "JPG" into "jpg".i think your file extension might be in lowercase letter and it might say f.exists false.
Hope it will help.

Comment: put a line e.printStackTrace inside catch block and show your stacktrace.

Comment: also show your code of method mCamUtils.clickPicture()

Answer (score 0):

```
 String fname = "Pic-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
 File image= new File(imagesFolder, fname);
Bitmap bitmap;

            BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            picturePath=image.getAbsolutePath();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

try this code